# Making my queries shorter, faster and better

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I'm running a large PHP script to get database info which is adapted for search queries and so on. The problem is that the loading time for the page is several seconds (locally) and up to a minute on remote databases.

I'm not the best one when it comes to optimizing, but I know but the asterisk in queries, but in this case I need it because I'm using all fields in the table.

Keep in mind that the table it gets data from has over 800k rows in total (no im not showing 800k rows, as seen in the code I'm showing it `WHERE = something`)

```
<?php

    $getPage = $mysqli->real_escape_string(@$_GET["page"]); 
    $getSearch = $mysqli->real_escape_string(@$_GET["search"]);
    $getUser = $mysqli->real_escape_string(@$_GET["user"]);

    if(isset($getPage)) { $page  = $getPage; } else { $page = 1; }; 
    $start_from = ($page-1) * 12;

    $order = $mysqli->real_escape_string(@$_GET["ord"]); 

    $order_query = "item_name ASC";

    if($start_from >= 0) {
        if($getSearch)
        {
            if($order)
            {
                if($order == 1)
                {
                    $order_query = "item_name ASC";
                }

                if($order == 2)
                {
                    $order_query = "item_name DESC";
                }

                if($order == 3)
                {
                    $order_query = "item_id ASC";
                }

                if($order == 4)
                {
                    $order_query = "item_id DESC";
                }

                $shop = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM store_inventory WHERE (item_name LIKE '%".$getSearch."%' OR item_type LIKE '%".$getSearch."%' OR item_quality LIKE '%".$getSearch."%')  AND steamid = '".$getUser."' GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY ".$order_query." LIMIT $start_from, 28");
            }
            else
            {
                $shop = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM store_inventory WHERE (item_name LIKE '%".$getSearch."%' OR item_type LIKE '%".$getSearch."%' OR item_quality LIKE '%".$getSearch."%')  AND steamid = '".$getUser."' GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY item_name ASC LIMIT $start_from, 28");
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if($order)
            {
                if($order == 1)
                {
                    $order_query = "item_name ASC";
                }

                if($order == 2)
                {
                    $order_query = "item_name DESC";
                }

                if($order == 3)
                {
                    $order_query = "item_id ASC";
                }

                if($order == 4)
                {
                    $order_query = "item_id DESC";
                }

                $shop = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM store_inventory WHERE steamid = '".$getUser."' GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY ".$order_query." LIMIT $start_from, 28");
            }
            else
            {
                $shop = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM store_inventory WHERE steamid = '".$getUser."' GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY item_name ASC LIMIT $start_from, 28");
            }
        }
    } else {
        $start_from = 0;
        if($getSearch)
        {
            if($order)
            {
                if($order == 1)
                {
                    $order_query = "item_name ASC";
                }

                if($order == 2)
                {
                    $order_query = "item_name DESC";
                }

                if($order == 3)
                {
                    $order_query = "item_id ASC";
                }

                if($order == 4)
                {
                    $order_query = "item_id DESC";
                }

                $shop = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM store_inventory WHERE (item_name LIKE '%".$getSearch."%' OR item_type LIKE '%".$getSearch."%' OR item_quality LIKE '%".$getSearch."%')  AND steamid = '".$getUser."' GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY ".$order_query." LIMIT $start_from, 28");
            }
            else
            {
                $shop = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM store_inventory WHERE (item_name LIKE '%".$getSearch."%' OR item_type LIKE '%".$getSearch."%' OR item_quality LIKE '%".$getSearch."%')  AND steamid = '".$getUser."' GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY item_name ASC LIMIT $start_from, 28");
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if($order)
            {
                if($order == 1)
                {
                    $order_query = "item_name ASC";
                }

                if($order == 2)
                {
                    $order_query = "item_name DESC";
                }

                if($order == 3)
                {
                    $order_query = "item_id ASC";
                }

                if($order == 4)
                {
                    $order_query = "item_id DESC";
                }

                $shop = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM store_inventory WHERE  steamid = '".$getUser."' GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY ".$order_query." LIMIT $start_from, 28");
            }
            else
            {
                $shop = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM store_inventory WHERE  steamid = '".$getUser."' GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY item_name ASC LIMIT $start_from, 28");
            }
        }
    }

    $countarticles = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(item_id) FROM store_inventory");
    $row = $countarticles->fetch_row();
    $total_records = $row[0]; 
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / 28);

    $Pages[] = "";        
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) { 
        $Pages[] = "<li><a href='?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
    }

    while($fetch_market = $shop->fetch_array())
    {
        $iInv[] = $fetch_market;
    }
```

How can I reduce the loading time of the script/page significantly?

Comment: first of all avoid using select * until and unless you need the full row

Comment: @DhavalChheda As I said, I need the full row.

Comment: do you have an index on steamid?

Comment: Nope, no index on steamid

Comment: adding an index will reduce your read time but if you have a write intensive operation then it will increase your write time also slightly

Comment: Indexes are great, mysql tuning (cache, memory), then server performance (cpu, type of disks, ...).

Comment: Ah thanks, indexing seems to speed it up by a lot!

Comment: If this is a table that you will write to infrequently but read from many times, you may want to use the MyISAM engine (with proper indexes and/or unique keys) and compress the table.

Since this solution makes the table read-only, it is not a good solution for tables which are updated frequently.

Comment: @P.Nick when you ask for query optimization help, please include the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table in your query so we don't have to guess at data types, indexes, and constraints. Help us help you!

Comment: Show us some sample generated queries.  Show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, so we can critique the index(es).  Don't blindly use `TEXT` or `VARCHAR(255)`, use reasonable datatypes.  Do _not_ use MyISAM; it is dying; use InnoDB; anyway it is almost always faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your select query.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM store_inventory
 WHERE (   item_name LIKE '%".$getSearch."%'
        OR item_type LIKE '%".$getSearch."%'
        OR item_quality LIKE '%".$getSearch."%'
       )
   AND steamid = '".$getUser."'
 GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY ".$order_query."  
 LIMIT $start_from, 28
```

With respect, the way you have written this query is guaranteed to be very slow.

Why?

First, you are using `WHERE column LIKE '%value%'`. That kind of filter expression cannot possibly be sped up by an index. Why not? Because it has to look at every value in the column to see whether it matches your expression.  `WHERE column LIKE 'value%'`, on the other hand, without the leading `%`, can exploit an index. The way you have it requires a full table scan to perform your filter.

Second, you are using three `OR` expressions, each with that poorly performing `LIKE` filter. That turns your one table scan into three, tripling the time taken.

Third, you are misusing `GROUP BY` here. MySQL lets you get away with all kinds of strange stuff here. Read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html I would make a suggestion about how to fix this, but I can't guess what you're trying to do.

Fourth, you are using the notorious `SELECT * ... ORDER BY x LIMIT y` performance antipattern. That sorts a whole mess of rows, only to discard all but a few of them.

What can you do about this? First of all, make sure you have an index on that `steamid` column. If it is reasonably selective, that will help a lot by reducing the number of rows needing scanning.

Second, try replacing your `steamid` index with a compound index on

```
steamid, item_name, item_type, item_quality
```

That *may* (or may not) make your `LIKE` scans more efficient.

Third, figure out what you're actually trying to accomplish with `GROUP BY` and try to do it correctly.

Fourth, try to reduce the burden on `ORDER BY`.  Something like this may help.

```
SELECT * FROM store_inventory
 WHERE id IN (SELECT id
                FROM store_inventory
               WHERE (    this
                       OR that
                       OR the_other_thing
                     )
                 AND steamid = something
               ORDER BY some_column
               LIMIT start, count
              )
```

This makes it so MySQL only has to sort the ids. It's faster.

Fifth, look up MySQL's FULLTEXT searching option. It may replace your series of `LIKE` operations with something far more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Looking into it!

Answer (score 0):

### **Use PHP 7, Prepared Statements and Functions!**

**Why use PHP 7?** 
PHP 7 is twice faster than PHP 5.6 according to [Anna Monus][1]

**Why use Prepared Statements?** 
PHP7 + MySQLi gives better performance and security. However, your code is still vulnerable to SQL injection. NOTE that Prepared Statements can be slow. **Prepared statements become faster only when you're preparing the statement and then executing it multiple times.** But since you're using mysqli_real_escape_string, which does a roundtrip to the database, by replacing all of those roundtrips with a single prepared statement makes your code faster.

**Why use functions** 
Functions makes your code shorter, easier to maintain and in most cases, execute faster. Since you're constantly repeating your code. You can shorten it up by using function(s).

I know this is long enough so here is your code:

```
$getPage = $mysqli->real_escape_string(@$_GET["page"]); 
$getSearch = $mysqli->real_escape_string(@$_GET["search"]);
$getUser = $mysqli->real_escape_string(@$_GET["user"]);

if(isset($getPage)) { $page  = $getPage; } else { $page = 1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * 12;

$order = $mysqli->real_escape_string(@$_GET["ord"]); 

$order_query = "item_name ASC";

function order_item($order) {
    if($order == 1) {
        $order_query = "item_name ASC";
    }
    if($order == 2) {
        $order_query = "item_name DESC";
    }
    if($order == 3) {
        $order_query = "item_id ASC";
    }
    if($order == 4) {
        $order_query = "item_id DESC";
    }
return $order_query;
}

function shop_type($type, $orderBy) {
    $getSearch = "%$getSearch%";
    if ( $type = 'searched' ) {
        $add = "AND (item_name LIKE ? OR item_type LIKE ? OR item_quality LIKE ?)";
    } else {
        $add = "";
    }
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM store_inventory 
        WHERE steamid = ? 
        ".$add."
        GROUP BY item_id
        ORDER BY ".$orderBy." ASC
        LIMIT $start_from, 28"); 
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $getUser, $getSearch);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if($result->num_rows === 0) exit('No rows');
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $arr[] = $row;
    }
    return $arr;
}

function get_items() {
     if($getSearch) {
        if($order) {
            order_item($order);
            $shop = shop_type('searched',$order_query);
        } else {
            $shop = shop_type('searched','item_name');
        }
    } else {
        if($order) {
            order_item($order);
            $shop = shop_type('unsearched',$order_query);
        } else {
            $shop = shop_type('unsearched','item_name');
        }
    }
}

if($start_from >= 0) {
   get_items();
} else {
    $start_from = 0;
    get_items();
}

$countarticles = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(item_id) FROM store_inventory");
$row = $countarticles->fetch_row();
$total_records = $row[0]; 
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 28);

$Pages[] = "";        
for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) { 
    $Pages[] = "<li><a href='?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
}

while($fetch_market = $shop->fetch_array())
{
    $iInv[] = $fetch_market;
}
```

### ANOTHER TIP:

Put the function(s) in a separate PHP file and call it using:

```
require "filename.php";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: With respect, this is good advice but not responsive to the question.

Comment: I am very sorry to hear that. But as far as I am concerned I made his code (1) shorter (2) faster and hopefully (3) better. :D

Comment: Sometimes its faster, sometimes its x10 slower. Not sure what's causing that.

Comment: I forgot to mention that LIKE queries are slow. try using other queries as suggested by O. Jones. Also try to check execution speed by using microtime; this may pinpoint the problematic function/queries so we can help you with better answers.